# EF5 with Many to Many Relationship creates cyclic reference when serializing to JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, knockout.js

I have an Entity Framework 5 Code First model with a many to many relationship
i.e.

```
Public class Product
{
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Category> Categories {get;set;}
}

Public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

I'm creating the actual relation in fluent, thus;

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Categories)
            .WithMany(c => c.Products)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("ProductsToCategories");
                    m.MapLeftKey("Products_ProductId");
                    m.MapRightKey("ProductCategories_ProductCategoryId");
                });
```

Now when I retrieve my data is is retrieving Product, and Product as a bunch of Categories, BUT each Category also has a bunch of products in it as well, and so it recurses around.

The problem is that this is causing havoc when I then serialise it to JSON for use by the front end (I'm using KnockOut, but that is kind of irrelevant).

I've tried turning Lazy loading off, and when I get my products I use an include;

```
db.Products.Include("Categories").ToList()
```

but this is still then performing the recursive gathering of products within each Category.

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use business objects instead of using database objects directly. In this manner you only reference from on side, say :

```
Public class Product
{
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public IList<Category> Categories {get;set;}
}

Public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have reference cyclic between Product and Category.
In other words Product have a relation to Category and Category have a relation to Product.
So, what you need to do is to delete one of these relations.

I would do someting like that :

```
var categoriesGraph = db.Categories.Include("Products").ToList();
var data = categoriesGraph.Select(c => new
{
    c.CategoryId,
    Products = c.Products.Select(p = > new {
        p.ProductId,
        CategoriesID = p.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryId).ToArray(),
         // don't add the categories.
    }).ToArray()
}).ToArray();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  Both answers will do what I need!  I was sort of hoping to not use Business or View Models, but in the end I think that might best solve this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Json.Net to just ignore circular references:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

If you want references to existing data, then you look at fix 2 in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongyes/archive/2012/09/04/loop-reference-handling-in-serializer.aspx)